# Pentaho Business Analyzer Adding Timestamp

Tags: business-intelligence, pentaho-report-designer

In the pentaho business analyzer, I am using just the date in my dimension table.

The dates are in yyyy-MM-dd format. For example, 2016-10-01.

When I go to use SQL to pull dates out of my date_dimension table, it keeps adding a timestamp.

It doesn't do it in the analyzer reports, just when I use SQL for the prompts.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the support team from Pentaho.

Actually, there was nothing I could do to fix this as this was a bug on their end.

I ended up changing the data type to a string data type. Now everything works fine.